# c# увеличение переменных на 1

Tags: c#

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(zvon.textBox1.Text);
int zTime1 = (dt1.Hour * 60 + dt1.Minute);
//
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(zvon.textBox2.Text);
int zTime2 = (dt2.Hour * 60 + dt2.Minute);
//
DateTime dt3 = DateTime.Parse(zvon.textBox3.Text);
int zTime3 = (dt3.Hour * 60 + dt3.Minute);
```

Можно как то по аналогии сверху, не методом ctrl+c, ctrl+v сделать что бы значения dt, textBox, zTime, увеличивались с 1 до 84?

Comment: Объединить всё в массив и пройтись циклом?

Comment: А как можно DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(zvon.textBox1.Text);
int zTime1 = (dt1.Hour * 60 + dt1.Minute); эту строку всунуть в цикл до 84?

Comment: А зачем вообще 84 увеличивать это всё дело в цикле, почему нельзя прибавить сразу 84?

Comment: Потому что есть 84 бокса и каждому должно быть присвоено свое значение

Comment: Вам нужно у всех TextBox'ов просто увеличить время или собрать все эти данные и уже потом их увеличить?

Comment: У каждого бокса есть свое время. Пример: 8:50, далее это время разбивается на часы и минуты и находится время, далее это время используется в условии. Мне нужно что бы у каждого бокса были присвоены свои переменные, боксов всего 84, можно ли как то сделать не расписывая 160 страниц кода, предоставленного сверху

Comment: Да уж, очень странный софт у вас, видимо. Объедините все TextBox'ы в массив, потом в цикле проходите по ним и стройте List/Dictionary. Если с этим будут проблемы - значит вы рано взялись за разработку такого ПО, сначала изучайте основы C#

Comment: Когда мне нужно писать много строк однотипных, но с переменным значением, я просто пишу код, который его генерирует) Не обязательно создавать новый проект ради пары строк, есть онлайн решение - https://sharplab.io